# Добавление компонентов по нажатию

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть идея, но не знаю как реализовать. Хочу сделать что-то вроде программы для записок. Суть в том что все заключается в добавлении компонентов если мы хотим что-то добавить или написать. Внизу есть панель которая спрашивает что мы хотим добавить. Текст? Тогда нажимаем и появляется `RichTextBox`. Еще изображение? Тогда появляется `PicrureBox` после `RichTextBox`. Еще код? Тогда появляется `FastColoredTextBox` после `PicrureBox`. Если еще текст нужен, то еще один `RichTextBox` после `FastColoredTextBox`. Получается такой чат с самим собой. Вопрос в том, как создавать эти элементы на форме? Чтобы они где-то были скрыты, а мы при нажатии как бы клонировали их и вставляли.

[image: Пример]

Comment: Очень интересный вопрос. А что именно не получается? Создайте эти три элемента управления и скройте. Затем клонируйте их, например, [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267292/1548895) и делайте видимыми.

Comment: Интереснее было бы не клонировать, а добавлять новые, например, в richTextBox заносить информацию из текстового файла выбранного пользователем, с остальным по аналогии

Comment: вместо WinForms подобное очень просто реализовать на WPF так что советую обратить внимание на эту технологию

Answer (score 2):

В чем, собственно, проблема?
Например, при нажатии на кнопку пишете код:

```
Label label2 = new Label();

    label2.AutoSize = true;
    label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(41, 92);
    label2.Name = "label2";
    label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
    label2.TabIndex = 1;
    label2.Text = "label2";
    Controls.Add(label2);
```

Создается Label, который отрисуется на форме по координатам Point(41, 92).
И можете так же создавать любой элемент. Можете присвоить каждому элементу все нужные свойства и прописать обработчики событий.

Если сильно нужно, создайте массив элементов object и все свои динамические элементы храните в нем. При желании, вы сможете обратиться к любому элементу и изменять его свойства и т.д...

Comment: А еще бросьте на форму flowLayoutPanel и вызывайте             
 flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label2); Лэйблы будут автоматически добавляться вниз панели. )

Answer (score 2):

```
void bKod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FastColoredTextBox fctb = new FastColoredTextBox();
    fctb.Width = this.Width;
    this.Controls.Add(fctb);
}

void bKartinka_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.Width = this.Width;

    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    panel.Controls.Add(pb);

    this.Controls.Add(panel);
}

void bTekst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
    rtb.Width = this.Width;
    this.Controls.Add(rtb);
}
```

**Заметка:** Для `FastColoredTextBox` будете изпользовать 3rd party controls ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087735/a-textbox-richtextbox-that-has-syntax-highlighting-c) или [CodeProject FastColoredTextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting)) или `CustomControl`